# How do I get back a directory that was deleted from svn and commited

Tags: linux, svn, revert

I have tried to search for a way to resolve this and have come up with nothing so far.

I made changes to certain files in a directory. I then performed an svn add and svn commit for those files I changed. Then (by accident) I deleted the directory in svn containing the files I just modified. (the directory names were different which is what caused the mix up).

My goal is to get back the directory I deleted with my modified files or get back just the modified files. I have tried using svn merge -c REV and recommitting. it first told me there was a tree conflict with the directory i deleted so i did an svn resolve --accept working PATH. I have also tried an svn merge -r (current):(previous) to no avail.

Please help. I am using Linux (centOS)

Comment: [Relevant section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.resurrect) from the Red Book.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk Undoing Changes is also very helpful IMO http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undoundo

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried to do an svn copy it changed the revision but none of the changes I was looking for are there. I am 150% certain I add added and committed the files before deleting the directory

Comment: If you committed those files and then deleted the directory in _two separate commits_, then you should see that in the log.  If you just need the modified files, run the `svn copy` command using the path/revision of those files rather than the directory.

Comment: The problem is there several files and I don't see that separated in the log. I am confident in which revision the changes were made. I just want to go back to that revision and have my directory (which was in the repository reappear).

Comment: Ok I figured out what I wasn't doing. After I did the copy I did not perform another svn update. Once I did that I saw all the changes come back. Thanks for your help